# Using the Concatenate function in an IF statement

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a string in excel cells, and it works to some extent, but when the value returns false I simply get "FALSE" in the cell, although when it returns a true value it actually changes the cell to what I have defined in the `IF` statement.

Is this because I have inserted the concatenate query incorrectly in the if statement?

My formula is as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ET2:ET4,B2)),"yes",F2=CONCATENATE("NA ",B2))
```

Comment: Not a programming question so should not be asked here. Better suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get false is the bit that says

```
F2=CONCATENATE("NA ",B2)
```

I think you're trying to use this as an assignment (ie set the cell F2 to the value of the ConCat).

What it will actually do is compare the value of F2 and the value of the concat, and return `TRUE` if they are equal and `FALSE` otherwise. This `TRUE` or `FALSE` value is what you are ending up with in your cell.

So to fix it:

If the above formula is in the cell F2, then just remove the `F2=` from the formula and it should work.

If the above formula not in the cell F2, then you need to put either this same formula or a slightly altered one into that cell to populate F2.